# Require help on Inner join query on single table

Tags: sql, database, hive

I have single table called TEST as follow :

```
job_id    input_id  match_outcome
101       1         MATCH
101       2         NO_MATCH
201       1         NO_MATCH
201       2         MATCH
```

Expected outcome:

```
job_id  input_id    match_outcome
201     1           NO_MATCH
101     2           NO_MATCH
```

Query I used:

```
select *
from ( select *  from TEST where job_id = '101') q1 join
     (select * from TEST where job_id = '201') q2
where q1.match_outcome= 'MATCH' and q2.match_outcome= 'NO_MATCH' OR
      q2.match_outcome= 'MATCH' and q1.match_outcome= 'NO_MATCH'
```

Overall objective:
I need input_id and other data which is MATCH with one job_id and and the input id which is NO MATCH in another set of job id.But this query takes longer times since these table contains millions of record and I didn't see the outcome yet.(Fyi, I am using hive tables) any efficient or any different better way to don this!! Thanks

Comment: Didn't somebody ask this question just about an hour ago? Check that question's answers!

Comment: Get serious. Although in text format, It is still the same unclear data sample.

Comment: I did.. I removed / closed it . since I attached multiple screen shots o explain

Comment: Your question is unclear. You don't need a join to get your desired result:
`SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE match_outcome='NO_MATCH'`. I assume that's not what you want.

Comment: Add some more sample data, perhaps double it, and adjust the expected result. Too little to describe the problem as it is now.

Comment: What is the table's key? `job_id` + `input_id` I suppose? And you want all 'NO_MATCH' records where also exists a 'MATCH' record for the same `input_id`?

Comment: Use more sentences with more workds to clearly explain what rows you want to get back from your query. Probably it would help if first you clearly explained what/when rows go into your original table.

Answer (score -1):

If I try to understand this:  "I need input_id . . . which is MATCH with one job_id and and the input id which is NO MATCH in another set of job id", then you can use aggregation:

```
select input_id
from text
group by input_id
having sum(case when match_outcome = 'MATCH' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when match_outcome = 'NO MATCH' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

This assumes that `input_id` is not duplicated for a give `job_id`, which seems consistent with the data in the question.

If you want the original data row, then you can `join` this into the query:

```
select t.*
from test t join
     (select input_id
      from text
      group by input_id
      having sum(case when match_outcome = 'MATCH' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
             sum(case when match_outcome = 'NO MATCH' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
    ) i
    on t.input_id = i.input_id;
```

Comment: Explanation for the downvote?  I think this is an accurate interpretation of the question.

Answer (score -2):

Select * from TEST
Where match_outcome='NO_MATCH'